# Should users that by now, should already have +2k but due to some reason have less than 2k, be suggesting edits?

Tags: discussion, editing, reputation, suggested-edits

I was observing that some users, by now, should already have 2k points or more, but due to say bounties here and there, have less than 2k.

Comment: Them's the breaks. I guess in theory it would be possible to code the system in such a way that a privilege like this is not lost if your rep falls below 2k. Then again, we would not want somebody to get to keep a privilege they "earned" by getting votes from a voting ring. Sounds like that would quickly become a bit too complicated to code.

Comment: I didn't bother to downvote this (in case you were wondering). However, I was about to comment that your suggestion, because it would necessitate software changes, should probably be posted in MetaStackExchange. Simply because the change would affect all the sites. The people reading Meta. Math.SE are largely powerless to do anything about it. You know, such a change could not be done on Math.SE alone. Anyway, then I saw t Glorfindel's answer that did away the need for me to dig up a related thread in MSE.

Comment: Your post is very terse for one intended to start a "discussion".  Perhaps you can provide more details of an objection to the way things are or a proposal to improve things.  As currently phrased your one sentence "observation" can be taken in a variety of senses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's a lot to edit, and they should certainly be suggesting edits if they do not have the privilege to edit directly.

Perhaps you meant that privileges should be "buttons" rather than "switches", that is, once you "unlock" a privilege, it remains accessible to you. But that's not how the software is designed.

If you lost your reputation due to any reason, you will lose the privileges associated with it.

Answer (score 6):

This has been requested [on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42834/295232) but effectively [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). Bottom line: you should only invest reputation you can miss in bounties, and accept that that might mean losing privileges.